# How to Resolve Error: Watchman error: watchman::RootResolveError:

Tags: node.js, react-native, macos, watchman

I am at a loss.

I have tried reinstalling watchman, I've tried deleting all watchman instances and then restarting my react native app. I can do `watchman watch .` in my project's directory and get a positive response.

I also have a `.watchmanconfig` file with an empty object (`{}`) in my project root.

I have tried the below:

```
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/root-state
```

I got no errors while running these commands but after doing them and then running `react-native start`.

I've also tried going to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access but in the list I can't find watchman to allow it access. It just doesn't show up.

The full error is below.

```
jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: watchman::RootResolveError: failed to resolve root: unable to resolve root .: failed to resolve root: path "." must be absolute. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.
```

I am out of ideas. Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Current Specs

```
OS: macOS Monterey 12.4
node: 16.5
watchman: 2022.06.06.00
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.64.0
```

Comment: I am getting the same error and nothing is working. Tried everything.

Answer (score 2):

> watchman watch-del-all

> watchman shutdown-server

> rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/root-state

I try this before run my react native App and its work

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that I tried that as well. I'll update the question.